# Erlang multiprocessing messages receiving and sending

Tags: erlang, multiprocessing, message

I'm studying the book "Learn you some Erlang".I have a couple of questions to implement on multiprocessing programming with Erlang. Basically, I was reading and imitating "Learn you some Erlang". And I have generated a program with some oriented functions in my program. It said fridge can be acted like itself to store and take. So I'm processing my program for some operations in a base obeyed followings:

- First, I need that the terminate message should correspond to the same form as store and take. Which means the message should be `{from, terminate}` and the receiver reply with the message `{self(), terminated}`.
- Second, I want to respond the sender an unorganized message `{From, Msg}` with the message `{self(), {not_recognized, Msg}}`.
- Third, to add an inventory message `{From, {inventory} }` will return to sender (From) the current `FoodList` in the fridge2 process.
- Fourth, to add a peek message `{From, {peek, a} }` will look in the items stored in the process.  If a is present, send the message back to the sender (From): `{present, a}`.  If a is
  not present, send the message back to the sender (From): `{not_present, a}`.

I'm totally confused about the usage of fridge itself. I've figured something like below with the sample code from tutorial:

```
-module(kitchen).
-compile(export_all).

fridge1() ->
receive
    {From, {store, _Food}} ->
        From ! {self(), ok},
        fridge1();
    {From, {take, _Food}} ->
        %% uh ...
        From ! {self(), not_found},
        fridge1();
    terminate             ->
            ok
end.

fridge2(FoodList) ->                        
receive
    {From, {store, Food}} ->
        From ! {self(), ok},
        fridge2( [Food | FoodList] );       
    {From, {take, Food}} ->
        case lists:member(Food, FoodList) of
            true   ->
                From ! {self(), {ok, Food}},
                fridge2(lists:delete(Food, FoodList));      
            false  ->
                From ! { self(), not_found},                    
                fridge2(FoodList)                           
            end;
    terminate            ->
        ok
end. 

store(Pid, Food) ->
Pid ! {self(), {store, Food}},
receive
    {Pid, Msg} -> Msg
end.

take(Pid, Food) ->
Pid ! {self(), {take, Food}},
receive 
    {Pid, Msg} -> Msg
end.

start(FoodList) ->
spawn(?MODULE, fridge2, [FoodList]).
```

Besides, here's some problems I've been thinking:

1. How could I create a fridge process? Or it's already there?
2. How could I create a cook process, passing it the fridge process pid?
3. How could I store item to the fridge then sleep for several seconds and eventually I could take an item out from the fridge?

It's perhaps not the most complex problem, but I could not find any documentation about this so I'd appreciate some of you might know the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering your questions:

> 1. How could I create a fridge process? Or it's already there?

Once you call `kitchen:start/1` from erlang shell or from another module, function `spawn(?MODULE, fridge2, [FoodList])` will spawn a process for you. Take a look at the documentation for more details: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn-3

> 2. How could I create a cook process, passing it the fridge process pid?

As I said in the first answer, `spawn/3`, which take a `module`, a `function` and `arguments` as parameters, is one of the functions you can use to spawn new processes. So, you should use it to spawn a process that receives `kitchen:fridge2/1` pid as argument, something like

```
Kitchen = kitchen:start([]),
Cook = spawn(cook_module, cook_function, [Kitchen]).
```

That way you will spawn a process which executes `cook_module:cook_function/1` and pass `Kitchen` (fridge pid) as the argument.

> 3. How could I store item to the fridge then sleep for several seconds and eventually I could take an item out from the fridge?

You can store items to the fridge using the `store/2` function, wait a bit (or several seconds, as you wish) and then, using the `take/2` function, take something out the fridge. Just like this:

```
Pid = kitchen:start([]), %% this will spawn a fridge process
kitchen:store(Pid, "delicious insect pie"), %% this will store a delicious insect pie in your fridge by executing the function fridge2( [Food | FoodList] );
timer:sleep(1000), %% this function will make the caller process sleeps for 1000 milliseconds (you can change it for your several seconds instead...)
kitchen:take(Pid, "delicious insect pie"). %% this will take the delicious insect pie out of the fridge, by executing the function fridge2(lists:delete(Food, FoodList));
```